# Navbar position fixed not working on IOS devices

Tags: ios, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, safari, css-position

I'm trying to make a fixed navbar in mobile devices and I can't achieve it in IOS (neither Safari nor Chrome). However, it works in Android Chrome, Windows Chrome and Desktop Chrome and Firefox quite well.

The element which id is #header-sidebar is the element I want to fix. I've done a js function for two things: it changes #topbar position between desktop and mobile and it fixes #header-sidebar to the top of the page in mobile devices. I've mixed js and jQuery and don't know if it might be a problem.

The CSS properties to fix #header-sidebar are these,

```
display:block;
float:none;
position:fixed;
right:15px;
top:0px;
width:375px;
z-index:2
```

I have tried to simplified my code in the following snippet.

Do you see something that may not be friendly with IOS?

Thank you!

```js
//header-sidebar show fixed
(function($){
    function fixedRespMenu(){
        if( $(window).width() < 1025 ){
            var graybar = document.getElementById("topbar");
            var menu = document.getElementById("header-sidebar");
            menu.appendChild(graybar);
            var headerContainer = document.getElementById("header-container");
            var menuHeight = $(menu).height().toString();
            headerContainer.style = "margin-top:"+menuHeight+"px;";
            menu.style = "position:fixed;display:block;background-color:#FFFFFF;left:15px;width:100%";      
        }
    }

    function restorePcMenu(){
        if( $(window).width() > 1024 ){
            var header = document.getElementById("header");
            var headerContainer = document.getElementById("header-container");
            var graybar = document.getElementById("topbar");
            var menu = document.getElementById("header-sidebar");
            header.insertBefore(graybar,headerContainer);   
            headerContainer.style = "";
            menu.style = "";
        }
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        restorePcMenu();
        fixedRespMenu();
    })

    $(document).ready(function(){
        fixedRespMenu();
    })
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#header-sidebar{
            background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
            border-bottom-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
            border-bottom-style:solid;
            border-bottom-width:1px;
            border-left-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
            border-right-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
            border-top-color:rgb(221, 221, 221);
            box-sizing:border-box;
            color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
            display:block;
            float:none;
            font-family:"Open Sans", sans-serif;
            font-size:14px;
            height:72px;
            left:15px;
            line-height:20px;
            margin-left:-15px;
            margin-right:-15px;
            outline-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
            outline-style:none;
            outline-width:0px;
            position:fixed;
            right:15px;
            text-align:center;
            top:0px;
            width:375px;
            z-index:2;
            -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Header sidebar fixed</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- START WRAPPER -->
    <div id="wrapper">
    <!-- START HEADER -->
    <div id="header">
        <div id="topbar">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="topbar-left"><div id="text-12" class="widget">         
                <div class="textwidget"></div>
                </div></div>
                <div id="topbar-right">
                    <div id="text-21" class="widget">            
                        <div class="textwidget">¡Envío <strong>GRATIS</strong> hasta fin de mes!</div>
                    </div>                            
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header-container" style="margin-top: 71px;">
            <div class="container">
                <div id="logo" class="no-tagline">
                    <a id="logo-img" href="/" title="Eureka Store">
                        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/EurekaStore219x61-01.svg" title="Eureka Store" alt="Eureka Store">
                    </a>      
                </div>
                <div id="header-sidebar" style="position: fixed; display: block; left: 15px; width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                    <div id="" class="nav main-nav mobile-clone">
                        <a href="#" class="menu-trigger fa fa-bars"></a>
                        <ul id="menu-inicio" class="level-1 clearfix">
                            <li id="menu-item-18884" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-children-23 dropdown">
                                <a href="#" style="padding-right: 3px;">CATEGORÍAS<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> ▾</span></a>
                                <div class="submenu clearfix"></div>
                                <ul class="sub-menu clearfix">
                                    <li id="menu-item-31672" ><a href="/categorias/altavoces/">        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" style="color:inherit; font-size: 14px"></i>Altavoces</a></li>
                                    <li id="menu-item-31674" ><a href="/categorias/auriculares/">        <i class="fa fa-headphones" style="color:inherit; font-size: 14px"></i>Auriculares</a></li>
                                    <!-- ... -->
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora expedita ut doloremque blanditiis, provident reprehenderit eum dolorem cum natus mollitia facere sint porro dolor, animi laborum numquam architecto. Nam, optio.</p>
    </div>
    </div>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have checked on mobile and the issue is that the CSS styles are not being applied on mobile.

I have directly copied your code into a fresh webpage and all works fine for me so it's likely some other javascript on your page is blocking this.

May I suggest an alternative though, instead of using JavaScript for this why not just use pure CSS something like below?

**HTML**

```
<div id="header-container">
   <div class="container">
      <div id="header-sidebar">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

   #header-sidebar {
      position:fixed;
      display:block;
      background-color:#FFFFFF;
      left:15px;
      width:100%
   }

}
```

No need for any JavaScript which should make it more compatible. Also there is no need to check the current status on every window resize and no need to inject elements which can get expensive.

Comment: Ok, I got it. I'm checking the status on every window resize since, in the original site, I modify the html position of the #topbar element for resolutions greater than 1024px with js. I'll try to find out the problematic js and the way to avoid my expensive js code.